# Using NSInvocationOperation to send messages back to the main thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I will give you a quick scenario, so that my question makes more sense.

Say that I use NSInvocationOperation to create a new thread, which will run indefinitely in the background.

Now, this thread will send messages every so often back to the main thread.

So, my question is, what is the best way to send these messages back to the main thread? Could I just use a singleton to manage the messages from the child thread? Or is there a better way of doing this.

I know that in Java I can just use a Handler to post messages back to the main thread, and they arrive in the order they were posted. And I know this isn't Java, but I just wanted to give you an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself - this article was very useful:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/loading-images-asynchronously-on-iphone-using-nsinvocationoperation

And also thanks to marko - that was a good read (+1).

Answer (score 4):

You want `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`. [Documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a)

Answer (score -1):

Use delegate. You have Objective-C example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

Comment: Thanks, that was a good read. So, that's the best way to communicate between the child and main thread? Is this thread-safe?

Comment: -1 Delegate has nothing to do with performing selectors on different threads.